# How can I integrate google pay(payment app in India) in react native?

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway, google-pay

I am developing an app in react native and it requires different payment gateways,one of which is Google Pay. How can I integrate Google Pay in it?

Comment: Have you read this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/web/googlepay-business) ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many libraries which you can use for payment systems as well as in-app or direct pay.

Here is some of them

https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments (this package is as you would need I guess)

https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap (For in app purchases)

Comment: Question clearly state about integrating google Pay

Comment: this answer is not relevant for the Google pay integration in react native please check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

npm has a package called:

```
react-native-google-pay
```

Please try to install the package as

```
npm i react-native-google-pay
```

For more information please read this [Documentation for Gpay with React Native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-pay).